# Not able to Render YQL JSON Output using HTML / Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xpath, yql

I am using following `YQL` query with `XPATH` to get data of some elements of a web page:

```
select *
from html 
where url="http://www.desidime.com" 
and 
xpath='//h5[@class="product_text"]'
```

I am trying to display the results in a simple HTML page, but I have no clue why it is not working. It has to be some super silly mistake.

Here is the code for my HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <style type='text/css'>
        #results {
            width: 40%;
            margin-left: 30%;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        // Parses returned response and extracts
        // the title, links, and text of each news story.
        function top_stories(o) {
            var output = '';
            var items = o.query.results.h5;
            var no_items = items.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < no_items; i++) {
                var title = items[i].a.content;
                output += "<h3>" + title + "</h3><hr/>";
            }
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Div tag for stories results -->
    <div id='results'></div>
    ishan1
                <!-- The YQL statment will be assigned to src. -->
    <script src='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%0Afrom%20html%20%0Awhere%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.desidime.com%22%20%0Aand%20%0Axpath%3D\"%2F%2Fh5%5B%40class%3D%22product_text%22%5D\"&format=json&callback='></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: define "*not working*", did you get any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the encoded XPath query is wrong. I got an error when trying to open URL you posted in my browser. Try to replace it with this one, this fixed the error and able returned valid JSON result for me :

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+html+where+url%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.desidime.com%22+and+xpath%3d%27%2f%2fh5[%40class%3d%22product_text%22]%27&format=json&callback=
```